# Library not found for -lcommonCrypto

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, compiler-errors, commoncrypto

I need to link my ios 5 app with CommonCrypto. The problem is that I can't compile due to this error: 'Library not found for -lcommonCrypto'... How can I solve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you take out `-lcommonCrypto`, does the app still compile?

Looking at [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847281/commoncrypto-is-no-longer-part-of-the-iphone-sdk-where-else-can-i-easily-get-a), it looks like all you need to do is include the correct #import lines in your .m file.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the reference and it compiled.